# В iframe-приложении Вконтакте при входе через ВК-приложение для Android/iOS не работает поле загрузки изображений <input type="file">

Tags: php, javascript, vkontakte-api, iframe

В iframe-приложении Вконтакте при входе через ВК-приложение для Android/iOS не работает поле загрузки изображений input type="file". Можно ли каким-то другим способом (используя Javascript, например) вызвать окно файлового менеджера для выбора изображения и последующей его загрузки на сервер средствами php?